# How to copy data from a webserver to a local hard disk with rsync?

Tags: networking, rsync

First of all, sorry for my absolute basic question. 
I have very little IT skills and need help.

I have to copy a webserver to a local hard disk,
and I'm trying to do it with rsync. 
I am on a MacBook, using the terminal interface. 
I'm logged in to the server as superuser.

I tried to do it with following command:

```
rsync -av root@example.com/var/ /Volumes/xxx
```

"/Volumes/xxx" is the local hard disk on my Computer.

I get this error response:

```
rsync: change_dir "/home/root//root@example.com/var" failed: No such file or directory (2)
rsync: change_dir#3 "/Volumes" failed: No such file or directory (2)
rsync error: errors selecting input/output files, dirs (code 3) at main.c(694) [Receiver=3.1.0]
```

How can I make this work?

Comment: What is ``abc@def.xxx/var/``?  (1) You say that you’re logging in to the server as superuser, so is `abc` actually `root` (i.e., are you saying `root@def.xxx/var/`)?  If so, why not ***say*** it?  If not, what is `abc`?  (2) Is `def.xxx` the name of the server?  It would be *much* clearer if you said something like `example.com` or *`(server_name)`*.  (3) You say that you have to “copy **all data** from a webserver”.  So, are you trying to copy `/var` from the webserver? … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  Also, (4) you are getting an error message that says there’s a problem with `/Volumes`.  So what is the output of `ls -ld /Volumes`?  Can you `cd` to `/Volumes`?  Can you (as your current, logged-in user) create files there? … … … … … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: Thanks Scott for your help and advices. I try to do my best!

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a colon:

```
rsync -av abc@def.xxx:/var/ /Volumes/xxx
```

Comment: OP might also find it useful to add the webserver configuration in their ~/.ssh/config file, so they can simply run `rsync -av myhost:/var/ /Volumes/xxx` instead. Saves the private key file, hostname, username, port, etc etc. Just a simple addition that helps me everyday that I'd thought I'd share.

Comment: Thanks @HackSlash. When I fill in the colon the answer is "The authenticity of host 'host_name' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is 'xx:xx:xx:xx'.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?" 
Entering "yes" the answer is:
"Warning: Permanently added 'server_name' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
root@example.com's password:"

Should I continue?

Comment: Yes, what you just did is added the server certificate to the list of known hosts. This is how your computer can trust the connection is actually with the correct server. You should not see this again until the certificate expires.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `ssh` for this task like this

`rsync -avzO -e "ssh" --progress username@server:/remote/path/* /local/path/`

optionally you can use `scp username@server:/remote/path/* /local/path/`